# Ventanas transparentes, crear Form transparente

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer un formulario **transparente** pero **no** asi los **controles**(TextBox,Label,Button, etc) que se ha agregado al formulario, con **C#**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar definiendo el `BackColor` de un color y ese mismo color aplicarlo como [TransparencyKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx)  :

```
 this.TransparencyKey = Color.Crimson;
 this.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
```

Con esto lograrías lo que deseas, el formulario transparente pero no los controles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra opción es usar la propiedad de opacidad, [Opacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) pero esto aplica para todo el formulario incluyendo los controles que contiene:

```
 frmTransparentForm.Opacity = 0.5;
```

donde `0.0` es transparencia completa y `1.0` opacidad completa.

Con esto se vera transparente tu Formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí un artículo:
**[Como crear formularios transparentes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/czke9azk(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Comment: Excelente!!! pero al agregar un label se ve el color asignado en los bordes...

Comment: @Jiskar si amigo, ese sería el único inconveniente, de hecho también en el boton que este enfocado.