# ¿Cómo difuminar formularios sin afectar a los controles que este contiene?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms

Estoy creando un menú personalizado. Pero cuando pongo la propiedad `opacity` en el formulario, todos los controles que este contiene también se difuminan.

¿Cómo hacer para que las propiedades que cambien en el formulario no afecten a los controles que este contiene?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero en tu imagen solo se está difuminando el fondo, ¿no?

Comment: @Error404: Si ves en el fondo del botón `UltraButton1`, puedes ver una línea debido a la transparencia.

Comment: @sstan A vale, me habían parecido nítidos respecto al formulario pero tienes razón que se ve la línea posterior.

Comment: Por favor, sube el código en el que defines la opacidad para meternos en contexto.

Comment: He agregado una respuesta, con opacity esto no se puede lograr...

Comment: Se puede lograr definiendo BackColor de un determinado color y ese mismo color aplicarlo como TransparencyKey, esto dentro del constructor de nuestra clase que extiende de Form : gracias bro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta pregunta me ha resultado muy intrigante, nunca lo había notado que en WindowsForms, la opacidad solo la tiene el `Form` y que la hereda a los controles que en ella contenga (me parece un error muy grande por parte de como se maneja esto) incluso en [MSDN sobre Form.Opacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) dice:

> El Opacity propiedad le permite especificar un nivel de transparencia
>   del formulario y sus controles.

Ahora bien, buscando, experimentando y experimentando, encontré una alternativas (para mi gusto no es totalmente convincente, pero es una "solucione" que se puede usar y servir dependiendo de lo que busques).

Dicha solución está en este [tema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135082/how-to-exclude-control-from-a-winform-opacity-in-c-sharp) en StackOverflow en inglés:

La idea es crear dos `Form`, uno en donde modificarás la propiedad `Opactity`, otro en donde se cambiar la propiedad `TransparencyKey`([aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx) dejo información sobre este control). El primero será el que de la transparencia y el segundo, contendrá los controles y será el que controle el movimiento de los dos `Forms`.

**FormOpacity**

Será un Form Vacío, que solo le cambiarás la propidad `Opacity`, en el Design o en el código, además instancias el `FormControles`:

```
public FormOpacity()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Opacity = 0.5;
    FormControles f = new FormControles(this);
    f.Show();
}
```

**FormControles**

Aquí debes de tener todos tus controles, debe de ser del mismo tamaño del otro form, usarás `TransparencyKey`, para hacer transparente el fondo y crearás un evento `Move`, para que siempre esté atrás el `FormOpacity`.

```
public Form1(Form backForm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.backForm = backForm;
    TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 240, 240); //color del Form
}

private Form backForm; //Variable para guardar el FormOpacity

private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backForm.Location = Location;
}
```

Aquí entonces como quedaría.

[image: Aquí está el resultado]

Al final esta fue la mejor solución que encontré, pues intenté [encrustar un Form dentro del Otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31610/incrustar-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-dentro-de-una-ventana-wpf), a ver sí lograba el mismo efecto, pero con una sola ventana, pero no tuve éxito.

Finalmente, como te digo, la verdad, esta opción no me ha gustado, pues tiene muchos problemas, como que tienes dos ventanas, y sí minimizas el `FormOpacity` ya no consigues el efecto deseado (Si minimizas el FormControles sí se minimizan las dos), pero espero te sirva un poco y ayude con tu problema. Para mí esto se solucionaría haciendo que cada control tenga su propiedad `Opacity`, pero bueno, eso ya no depende de nosotros.

Comment: Hola Randall. Te doy la recompensa porque 1) OP nunca volvió al sitio para aceptar una respuesta 2) Aunque tu mismo reconoces que tu solución tiene sus fallas, es la única respuesta que mas o menos logra manejar el opacity. Es posible que con mas tiempo y esfuerzo, que tu solución pueda ser mejorada, pero el punto es que dejastes un fundamento que tal vez pueda ayudar a alguien a resolver este problema. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias @sstan, claro yo también noté que el OP no volvió al sitio. Muchas gracias, yo también espero que esto pueda servir para futuras personas que tengan un problema como este y que puedan mejorar mi solución y hasta compartirla.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede lograr definiendo `BackColor` de un determinado color y ese mismo color aplicarlo como [TransparencyKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx), esto dentro del constructor de nuestra clase que extiende de `Form`  :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        ...

        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Green;
        this.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

**Con esto lograrías lo que deseas, el formulario transparente pero no los controles que contiene**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo en VB.NET, al inicializar, definimos los mismos colores :

```
  Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        ...
        ...
        Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Green
        Me.BackColor = Color.Green
  End Sub
```

y obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambiar la propiedad `Opacity` no funciona en este caso, agregue una [**respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22940/95) anteriormente donde se puede ver.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la forma de hacerlo completamente transparente (cambiando el color puedes seleccionar otros tonos):

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
    {            
        get {
            CreateParams cp =  base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
            }
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) 
    {
        //base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    }
}
```

Copiado de este post del foro en inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463363/how-can-i-set-the-opacity-or-transparency-of-a-panel-in-winforms